# Returns System.Object

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I'm passing a `List<object>` to a method that populates a `checkedListBox`. My understanding is `Object.ToString()` associates the object with the `checkedListBox` item and displays readable string. Object.Name accomplishes this, but then the data isn't associated with the item. How do I access the `ValueMember` property of the `checkListBox` item?

```
public void CategoryListBox(List<Category> categoryList)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();

    foreach (Category category in categoryList)
    {     
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(category);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please precise in the tage or in your question it is WinForms!

Comment: is `Category` your object, if so you can just override the `ToString` method to return what you want the list to display.

Comment: Don't forget to override the `ToString` method in `Category`: public class Category { // Your code public override string ToString() { return // TODO : Replace with your text } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ValueMember of `CheckBoxList`

From the answer of *Mr. codingbiz* I did some quick research for this control `checkListBox` about `ValueMember` Property, so obviously from Intellisense we can't navigate this `.DisplayMember`  and `.ValueMember` for `checkListBox`, so I figured it out that this Property is already included in `checkListBox` but not showing in it. [For more details](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/5ebd210e-4bb0-4ddd-a717-552d0ad38a3d/)

## To List all the name

By using Linq we can achieve this.

```
  public class Category
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
  }


  List<Category> category = new List<Category>();
  category.Add(new Category { Id = 1, CategoryName = "test"  });
  category.Add(new Category { Id = 2, CategoryName = "let" });
  category.Add(new Category { Id = 3, CategoryName = "go" });
  checkedListBox1.DataSource = category;
  checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
  //checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Id"; 
  //checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(category.Select(c => c.CategoryName).ToArray());
```

I hope you can get some idea from this answer.

Comment: It is not my class, It is included in an API i'm using. I was really hoping the `CheckListBox.DisplayMember = category.Name` would work, it compiles but returns nothing. I think for my purposes generating a dictionary would be the easiest solution. I would have both the name of the category and the category available to me. `Dictionary<string, Category> categories = new Dictionary<string, Category>();` Thank you.

Comment: okay, if that so, the hint is already in my answer and i guess you don't need to use a `Dictionary` for the `Category<T>` only, i already updated my answer.